# Obj.entries not formatting correctly

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have a json file that is structured like so:

```
0: '{make: "John Deere", model: "4010", year: "1958", uid: "-KzPj2RoB0CatW_vpfwq"}'
1:'{make: "John Deere ", model: "4035", year: "1957", uid: "-KzPj691JCexVHixlSMv"}'
```

I want to turn it into an array of keys and pairs using Object.entries

```
const array1 = Object.entries(myObj); //myObj is the json
```

But when I execute this code, it's returning an array with this structure:

```
0: "-KzPj2RoB0CatW_vpfwq"
1: make: "John Deere" model: "4010" year: "1958"
  __proto__: Object
  uid: 0
```

Where the original "uid" takes the index of 1 (without the key "uid") and the rest of the key pairs take index 2. Then below, "uid" is assigned a new single digit.

I'm coding in React-Native.  Any insight to why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The file code block doesn't look like valid json. How are you loading and parsing the json?

Comment: Please click `<>` and add a [mcve] - your "JSON" looks like an array of strings

Comment: Don't you have to parse it first?

Comment: I probably didn't write the json correctly.  That's how it appears when I console.log the objects returned from Firebase.  But all of your comments have caused me to actually look at the structure of the json returned from Firebase, and sure enough, the returned json is in the structure Obj.entries is creating.  Stupid mistake.  Thanks everyone for giving me clarity!